# Interleaving Vertices and Texture Coords and Normals

Tags: optimization, opengl, textures

My buddy read an OpenGL book that said interleaving your vertex pointers and the corresponding texture coords etc to be next to each other in a larger array gives a speed boost.

How much of a speed boost?
On which chip sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just increases the data locality for the driver, potentially speeding up geometry submission.

Comment: Yeah I asked a guy who works for NVIDIA.  He said it's about getting the cache to work in your favor -- essentially the same answer.